# Running multiple jobs with unique name using qsub

Tags: bash, hpc, pbs

I have a bunch of text (input) files with the name

```
foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_file.in
foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_file.in
foo_bar_abc_1_03_geh_file.in
...
...
foo_bar_abc_1_1000_geh_file.in
```

I use following command to run these multiple jobs (in a HPC cluster)

```
for f in foo*.in; do qsub -N test -v infile=$f run.pbs
```

The problem in this one-line script is that the Job Name (in the cluster) is same for all the jobs in queue (i.e., test is the name for all jobs).

I would like to name each job something like test01, test02, test03...test1000 (numbers taken/extracted from the corresponding file names. For example,

```
   #For foo_bar_abc_1_01_geh_file.in, the Job Name should be test01,   
   #For foo_bar_abc_1_02_geh_file.in, the Job Name should be test02,   
   #For foo_bar_abc_1_100_geh_file.in, the Job Name should be test100,
   etc.
```

How to do this is bash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cut` like

```
for f in foo*.in; do qsub -N test$(echo $f|cut -d_ -f5) -v infile=$f run.pbs; done
```

where

- `-d_` sets delimiter character to `_` and
- `-f5` select only 5th column (i.e. the number of the job)